# Used MacBook Pro - Can't wipe drive and install clean version of MacOS

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, internet-recovery

Bought a used MCP mid-2015.  I am a novice, so my apologies up front.  The seller previously upgraded from a 256 GB SSD to a 1 TB SSD.  Seller did the upgrade himself and has been using it for some time.

I am trying to wipe the drive for a fresh install of MacOS.  When I attempt recovery mode via Command + R on restart, it automatically goes into Internet Recovery mode.  The boot drive MacSSD does not appear in Disk Utility.  Normally I would be able to erase the drive and reinstall MacOS.  In Terminal, this is what the list of disks looks like.  [image]

There is a volume labeled Nassif - Data.  Nassif is the previous owner.  Here is what Disk Utility looks like:

[image]

I feel like this container disk may be part of the problem.

[image]

I have tried creating a bootable USB so I could boot to that and then maybe have access to erase the MacSSD drive and reinstall MacOS, but I haven't had luck yet.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you asking us to list out steps to erase disk0 ( namely select it and then select erase in disk utility?) and the point here? https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-and-reinstall-macos-mh27903/mac

Comment: If you are asking how to create a bootable installer: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372